# Tetris generating coloured shapes from blocks

Tags: python, pygame, tetris

I'm making Tetris with Pygame. I have designed the blocks separately (a block in every color) so I need to let the game generate all of the blocks' shapes in all colors. I mean I want it to generate for example a shape composed of 4 red blocks in a row or a blue-coloured shape that looks like the letter L from those independent blocks... Then I would create a list in which I would store all these shapes to randomly generate them after.

And these are ones of those independent blocks:

```
red_block = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\red.png')
blue_block = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\Salem\Documents\MyGame1\blue.png')
```

So from these, i want to make tetris shapes in pygame  to use them directly ingame without photoshop or any external software
[image: blue block]
[image: green blocks]
[image: purple block]
[image: red block]
[image: yellow block]

Resume :
[image] --->>>  [image] (This is only a possible case)

Comment: So, what's your question, exactly?

Comment: For Tetris you would be better of manually typing the block combinations. There are not that many of them and especially getting the colors right in a algorithm will probably take you significantly more time.

Comment: @mousetail but how?

Comment: @sloth look again at the post, i edited it

Comment: Silly question, but should the tiles be the same size?

Comment: I still don't get it. Do you need help arranging the tiles into Tetris shapes?

Comment: @Rabbid76 yeah they should, but nevermind, this is not my goal now, i need to arrange them as you said and i'm having trouble doing that

Comment: i'm just looking for the method with which i can arrange them and then i would make them same size quickly, it's not an issue

Comment: @SalemJebnoun ""[...]  nevermind, this is not my goal now [...]"" - You're wrong, it's your goal now. To arrange them, you need to know the size of a single tile.

Comment: @Rabbid76 ok i'm doing it now, however a single tile is 31x31 px

Comment: @SalemJebnoun Now you have solved the problem yourself. The distance between adjacent tiles is 31.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tetris tiles are arranged in a grid. Define a list of shapes. Each shape is a list. The list contains tuples specifying the column and row of each tile that makes up the shape:

```py
shapes = [
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)],
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)],
    # [...] add more
]
```

Create a function that can be used to draw a single shape of the list:

```py
def draw_shape(x, y, tile_index, surf):
    w, h = surf.get_size()
    for pos in shapes[tile_index]:
        screen.blit(surf, (x + pos[0]*w, y + pos[1]*h))
```

---

Complete example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

tile_size = 20
red_tile = pygame.Surface((tile_size, tile_size))
red_tile.fill("red")
blue_tile = pygame.Surface((tile_size, tile_size))
blue_tile.fill("blue")
green_tile = pygame.Surface((tile_size, tile_size))
green_tile.fill("green")
yellow_tile = pygame.Surface((tile_size, tile_size))
yellow_tile.fill("yellow")

shapes = [
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (3, 0)],
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)],
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)],
    [(0, 0), (1, 0), (2, 0), (1, 1)],
    # [...] add more
]

def draw_shape(x, y, tile_index, surf):
    w, h = surf.get_size()
    for pos in shapes[tile_index]:
        screen.blit(surf, (x + pos[0]*w, y + pos[1]*h))

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    screen.fill(0)
    draw_shape(70, 70, 0, red_tile)
    draw_shape(170, 70, 1, blue_tile)
    draw_shape(70, 170, 2, green_tile)
    draw_shape(170, 170, 3, yellow_tile)
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```